# EF Loosing connection with field on database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Ok I dont understand this I have a field on the database its their can see it its in int field. Its the EnquirySourceId id field that you can see their and the table is called Enquiry
[image]

I have a class here called Eqnuiry View but why on earth does the  EnquirySourceId get destroyed every time its rebuilt. I see it on my enquiry object in my edmx. When I added it onto my partial view as such

```
public int EnquirySourceId { get; set; }
```

The reason I am asking is even though the database has the values correct when I look in the code the EnquirySourceId  is not being filled in I dont get this and its driving me nuts.

[image]

```
public partial class EnquiryView
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int EnquiryID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EnquiryDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int EnquiryAssignedToID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string EnquiryAssignedTo { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public int EnquiryStatusID { get; set; }
    public string JobSubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Edit 2

Check the settings as the chap in the comments suggested but it is table mapped.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried completely removing all classes from the edmx and regenerating it?  I used to have a similar problem a few years ago.  Somewhere in the edmx xml file, there will be an option to remove that field.  You need to remove it.  Why not search through the xml for that field name and see what you find?

Comment: Sorry but why would I wish to remove it and yes I have tried removing the field from the modal browser and also the edmx still same issue which is driving me nuts.

Comment: Check the table mappings in the EDMX. The property `EnquirySourceId` should be mapped to the column `EnquirySourceId`.

Comment: @GertArnold checked table mappings its their, all other values are comming through ok except the field i added annoying much

Comment: @GertArnold Turns out the developer had been using a stored proc which I was not aware of when I started searching the files i saw it and low and behold the field is staying.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around stack overflow I opened up my XML file and found that there was a view I didn't any about being referenced. I thought the partial view was a self-made one but it turns out it was being generated by the view that was not documented. Document your code people can save another developer hours of hunting around.